# Azure functions - read a file from disk and return HTML page

Tags: node.js, function, azure, fs

I'm testing Azure Node Functions locally on my Linux box.

When this is triggered:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    readFile = require('../SharedCode/readFile.js');
    filepath = __dirname + '/../bootstrap-HTML-page/static/simple.html'
    fs = require('fs');

    fs.readFile(filepath,function(error,content){
      if(error) {
        content = error;
      }
      if(content) {
        context.res = {
          status: 200,
          headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html'
              },
          body: content
        }
      }
    })
};
```

Then I get an empty response.

However if I run this, then I get the expected response:

```
context.res = {
      status: 200,
      headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
          },
      body: '<html> <body> <h1> test </h1> </body> </html>'
    }
```

I've checked the variable `content` and can see my HTML page in there. I can't figure out why it is not responding with the page.

**EDIT:** I think this is because the built in API fs can't handle promises and you need use something like promisify to make it work as an async function

Answer (score 3):

[I think this answer explains why it isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46867579/10740837)

and

[This one how to make it work as a normal (non-async) function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42584428/10740837)

this is my amended code that now works:

```
var fs = require('fs');


module.exports = function (context, req) {
    var filepath = __dirname + '/../bootstrap-HTML-page/static/simple.html'
    fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf8', function (err, content) {
        if (err) {
            context.log.error(err);
            context.done(err);
        }
        //context.log(result.name);
        context.res = {
        status: 200,
        headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            },
        body: content
      };
        context.done();
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your code is, even though you have added `async` in your function declaration, you forgot to wait for the asynchronous fs.readFile operation to complete via the `await` keyword. Since it doesn't exist, your code execution continues in a normal fashion, which reaches the end of the method and hence returns an empty response.

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    readFile = require('../SharedCode/readFile.js');
    filepath = __dirname + '/../bootstrap-HTML-page/static/simple.html'
    fs = require('fs');

    await fs.readFile(filepath,function(error,content){
      if(error) {
        content = error;
      }
      if(content) {
        context.res = {
          status: 200,
          headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html'
              },
          body: content
        }
      }
    })
};
```

Comment: Thanks Danyal, I did try that previously and it still doesn't return anything. If I `console.log(content)` then I can see the contents of my page, I'd expect it to return either a promise or undefined, if it was still waiting on the disk read...