# How to read a file from an Azure Function in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function and a file called configAPI.json which are located in the same folder as shown in the image below.

[image]

I want to read the latter with the following code based on this post [How can i read a Json file with a Azure function-Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42578431/how-can-i-read-a-json-file-with-a-azure-function-node-js) but the code isn't working at all because when I try to see if there's any content in the configAPI variable I encounter `undefined`:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = context.executionContext.functionDirectory + '//configAPI.json';
    configAPI= fs.readFile(path, 'utf-8', function(err, data){
        if (err) {
            context.log(err);
        }
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        return result
    });

   for (let file_index=0; file_index<configAPI.length; file_index++){
       // do something

  }
context.log(configAPI);
}
```

What am I missing in the code to make sure I can read the file and use it in a variable in my loop?

Comment: why do you have double // in '//configAPI.json'; ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`functionDirectory` - give you path to your functionS app then you have your single function

I think you should do:

```
const path = context.executionContext.functionDirectory + '\\configAPI.json';
```

In case you want to parse your json file you should have:

```
const file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(context.executionContext.functionDirectory + '\\configAPI.json'));
```

PS. context has also variable `functionName` so other option to experiment would be:

```
    const path = context.executionContext.functionDirectory + 
+ '\\' +context.executionContext.functionName + '\\configAPI.json';
```

Comment: I was able to locate my file with your last code  but now I am unable to read the JSON file with `JSON.parse(const path = context.executionContext.functionDirectory + 
+ '/' +context.executionContext.functionName + '/configAPI.json';`.

Comment: @abautista thats why i wrote to experiment since i was not sure what exactly  is stored in functionName

Comment: With both snippets I receive my file location as a string type and this is the output of your code: `C:\home\site\wwwroot\OptoHttpTriggerTest/OptoHttpTriggerTest/configAPI.json`. I tried to use `JSON.parse()` but that doesn't look to work. How can I parse this location as a JSON?

Comment: @abautista if you can read file and have issues with parsing json then please create other question and provide details, how you doing it, what error you getting

Comment: I noticed that when I try to parse the file with `const file = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(context.executionContext.functionDirectory + '/' +'OptoHttpTriggerTest/configAPI.json').toString());` I encounter this error `Result: FailureException: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, 
open 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\OptoHttpTriggerTest/OptoHttpTriggerTest/configAPI.json`. I also noticed that `\\` become   `/` after the first OptoHttpTriggerTest

Comment: See the updated response.

Comment: @abautista did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Yes, it worked like a charm after I used `const path = context.executionContext.functionDirectory + '\\configAPI.json';`